# May two View subclasses work as two Fragment in one screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a little app wich contain MainActivity and two subclasses of View - FirstScreenView and SecondScreenView. 
Now MainActivity manages both subclasses and output them successive. 
I want to show both classes in one time in a one screen (in this layout - firstscreen.xml that is used instead of main.xml now. main.xml does not exist).
I know that this challenge can be overcome by applying the fragment. But my classes extends View, not Fragment. 
May two View classes work as two Fragment in one screen?
Please, tell me in what way and how should I solve this problem.
Thank you (and thanks Google Translate).

Answer (score 0):

Talking from a UI perspective, the app will look the same. Talking from a functional perspective, the app could do the same. The only difference is that if you use fragments, you will have to manage both lifecycles.

I rather preffer what you have done, working with these two views. Remember that if you work with custom views, it is a best practice to delegate its logic to the activity, something you will relay to the fragmeents in the case you use them.